# error while installing charm-crypto in Python3.8 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, pip, pycharm

I didn't understand the error, does anyone know what's the meaning of this error?

```
(venv) C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\Testing>pip install charm-crypto==0.43
Collecting charm-crypto==0.43
  Using cached Charm-Crypto-0.43.tar.gz (364 kB)
  WARNING: Requested charm-crypto==0.43 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/6b/2c2abcb66f62155a60f5ecfe6936f651ecb9a115a2203c1b1d60d0e8d15e/Charm-Crypto-
0.43.tar.gz#sha256=40c3b626103e5b7e42ecf28bc86e147250c6df199cb3a9f2f9f6568e379ecc0e, but installing version 0.0.0
ERROR: Requested charm-crypto==0.43 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/6b/2c2abcb66f62155a60f5ecfe6936f651ecb9a115a2203c1b1d60d0e8d15e/Charm-Crypto-0.43
.tar.gz#sha256=40c3b626103e5b7e42ecf28bc86e147250c6df199cb3a9f2f9f6568e379ecc0e has different version in metadata: '0.0.0'
```

Comment: If you download the file gz from "https://pypi.org/project/charm-crypto/#files" and run command "pip install Charm-Crypto-0.43.tar.gz" it works or you get the same error?